# undefined variable but it is defined in array

Tags: php

Why is my code saying that $publishRequest is undefined. it is really defined in the array

this is just a part of my code but this part is the part where the problem is hiding

already tried above the array:

php

```
$publishRequest = array()

if($status1=="up") {
    $publishRequest = array(
        "instance_id" => INSTANCE_ID,
        "name" => INSTANCE_NAME,
        "group" => INSTANCE_GROUP,
        "description" => "Running on Controller.Ligowave.com",
        "contents" => array(
            array(
                "name" => "Status",
                "contents" => array(
                    array(
                        "icon" => "information",
                        "type" => "label",
                        "title" => $name1,
                        "subtitle" => "Uptime is: " . $uptimetime1
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
} else {
   array(
       "icon" => "error",
       "type" => "label",
        "title" => $name1,
        "subtitle" => "Down since: " . $lastseendate1);
}

try {
    echo "<p>Publish</p>";
    $publishResponse = request(options, $publishRequest);
    echo "<p>".$publishResponse."</p></br></br>";
}
```

Comment: what is `options`?

Comment: What does $status1 contain before the IF?

Comment: If `$status1` is not `== 'up'` then you create an array in the ELSE but dont set it into the variable `$publishRequest`

Comment: You have syntax errors. Could please fix them first?

Comment: You need to set the array in the ELSE to $publishRequest too.

Comment: I have no syntax error this is a part of my code

Comment: `$publishRequest = array()` without semicolon is a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$status1` is not `== 'up'` then you create an array in the ELSE but dont set it into the variable `$publishRequest`

```
else {
   $publishRequest = array(
                        "icon" => "error",
                        "type" => "label",
                        "title" => $name1,
                        "subtitle" => "Down since: " . $lastseendate1);
}
```

Comment: no, $publishRequest  already defined before the if-else block

Comment: Well the array in ELSE is useless without it being assigned to something.

Comment: Weird, if you had $publishRequest defined before the IF it shouldn't be undefined.